# Setup the width, size and all of the barchart (seaborn)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have developed a bar plot using seaborn library of python.
Here the month section is having 3 months only, product section is having plenty of products and according to that quantity is there
Basically I can tell you all that when I print this dataframe then it gives 979 rows in total
and maybe products in each month are around 300 or maybe not
In the barplot the bars are very conjested I can't have a clear view which product has highest sell in one  month

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  db="trial"
)

cursor = db_connection.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql("select ProductName,Month,Bottle from merge where Bottle>0",db_connection)

mon=[]
prod=[]
quan=[]

for i in df.itertuples():
    mon.append(i.Month)
    prod.append(i.ProductName)
    quan.append(i.Bottle)

dfd = pd.DataFrame({"Month":mon,"Product":prod,"Quantity":quan})

sns.barplot(x="Month",y="Quantity",hue="Product",data=dfd,palette="Set1")

plt.show()
```

Here is the barplot which is coming up while executing this code snippet:

[image: Barplot]

Please help me out in displaying it more clearly.
Also tell me how to display the values that are occuring in blocks like structure as its written in database with japanese language and collation used is utf8.

Answer (score 1):

When there are many objects to visualize, it is necessary to narrow down the targets according to the purpose. The following is an example with sample data from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales) and then narrowed down to 2014, 2015 and 2016, with limited category data.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

df = pd.read_csv('./Data/vgsales.csv', sep=',')
df = df[(df['Platform'] == 'NES') | (df['Platform'] == 'PS4') | (df['Platform'] == 'X360')]
df = df[(df['Year'] == 2014.0) | (df['Year'] == 2015.0) | (df['Year'] == 2016.0)]

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 432 entries, 33 to 16570
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   Rank          432 non-null    int64  
 1   Name          432 non-null    object 
 2   Platform      432 non-null    object 
 3   Year          432 non-null    float64
 4   Genre         432 non-null    object 
 5   Publisher     431 non-null    object 
 6   NA_Sales      432 non-null    float64
 7   EU_Sales      432 non-null    float64
 8   JP_Sales      432 non-null    float64
 9   Other_Sales   432 non-null    float64
 10  Global_Sales  432 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(6), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 40.5+ KB
df.head(10)
        Rank    Name    Platform    Year    Genre   Publisher   NA_Sales    EU_Sales    JP_Sales    Other_Sales Global_Sales
33  34  Call of Duty: Black Ops 3   PS4 2015.0  Shooter Activision  5.77    5.81    0.35    2.31    14.24
44  45  Grand Theft Auto V  PS4 2014.0  Action  Take-Two Interactive    3.80    5.81    0.36    2.02    11.98
77  78  FIFA 16 PS4 2015.0  Sports  Electronic Arts 1.11    6.06    0.06    1.26    8.49
92  93  Star Wars Battlefront (2015)    PS4 2015.0  Shooter Electronic Arts 2.93    3.29    0.22    1.23    7.67
93  94  Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare  PS4 2014.0  Shooter Activision  2.80    3.30    0.14    1.37    7.60
109 110 Fallout 4   PS4 2015.0  Role-Playing    Bethesda Softworks  2.47    3.15    0.24    1.10    6.96
124 125 FIFA 15 PS4 2014.0  Sports  Electronic Arts 0.79    4.29    0.05    1.47    6.59
154 155 Destiny PS4 2014.0  Shooter Activision  2.49    2.05    0.16    0.96    5.65
221 222 FIFA 17 PS4 2016.0  Sports  Electronic Arts 0.28    3.75    0.06    0.69    4.77
236 237 The Last of Us  PS4 2014.0  Action  Sony Computer Entertainment 1.78    1.87    0.07    0.82    4.55
```

Refine the number of sales in addition to the above criteria

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 9))
g = sns.barplot(data=df[df['Global_Sales'] >= 1.0], x='Name', y='Global_Sales', palette='tab20', ax=ax)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Graphing over multiple years by sales year

```
g = sns.catplot(data=df[df['Global_Sales'] >= 1.0], kind='bar', x='Name', y='Global_Sales', row='Year', palette='tab20', aspect=3, height=3)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

[image]

Categorized (by genre since it's a game)

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data=df[df['Global_Sales'] >= 1.0], col="Genre", hue="Name", palette="tab20", col_wrap=3)
grid.map(plt.bar, 'Year', 'Global_Sales')
grid.set(xticks=[2014.0,2015.0,2016.0], yticks=[0,20], ylim=(0, 21))
grid.fig.set_figheight(10)
grid.fig.set_figwidth(20)
grid.add_legend()
```

[image]